# XmlReader: Not reading sibling child elements

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Following is the code:

```
string str = "<A><B>Apple</B><B>Mango</B></A>";

using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str)))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "B")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Apple

**Supposed Output:**

Apple
Manglo

Can you please help me to understand what is wrong with this code? How do I get the supposed output?

**Note:** I want to achieve this with XmlReader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadElementContentAsString` reads and advances the reader to the next element.
So with the `Read` in the `while` you are skipping the next `B` element.

Instead use, the `Value` property.

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str)))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "B")
        {
            xmlReader.Read(); // Next read will contain the value
            Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish to show the outer xml then use it a bit differently:

```
bool hasMore = xmlReader.Read();
while (hasMore)
{
    if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "B")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.ReadOuterXml());
    }
    else hasMore = xmlReader.Read();
}
```

Comment: This solution works. But if I need to print OuterXml for each child, it doesn't!!

Comment: Thanks Ofir for the OuterXml solution

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody wants to know how to get the OuterXml for each child nodes as well use the child node value, following code can be used:

```
string str = "<A><B>Apple</B><B>Mango</B></A>";

using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str)))
{
    while (!xmlReader.EOF)
    {
        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "B")
        {
            XElement xElement = XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader) as XElement;
            Console.WriteLine(xElement.ToString());     // This will print the tag
            Console.WriteLine(xElement.Value);          // This will print the tag value
        }
        else
        {
            xmlReader.Read();
        }
    }
}
```